# whatever subdomain redirect to a specific folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, wildcard

I have the following structure

- webapp
- website
- .htaccess

and I have made a virtual host like the following

- mydomain.com -> points to -> website
- app.mydomain.com -> points to -> webapp

and I need to apply wildcard DNS concept to make any subdomain pointing to my webapp folder with keeping the subdomain in the url.
like 
    username.mydomain.com
    company-name.mydomain.com
    whatever.mydomain.com

and make them points to webapp folder

is there any virtual host or .htaccess way to do that?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/vhosts/name-based.html), the vhost resolution uses the definition order. The following config should do what you want :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.yourdomain.com
    ServerAlias yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /www/yourdomain/website
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /www/yourdomain/webapp
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *.yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /www/yourdomain/customsubdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache will route the request to the first vhost that matches the `ServerName` directive

- `yourdomain.com` will match the first one
- `www.yourdomain.com` will match the first one
- `app.yourdomain.com` will match the second one
- `companyname..yourdomain.com` the third one
- `username.yourdomain.com` the third one
- and so on...

`*.yourdomain.com` matches both `app.yourdomain.com` and `www.yourdomain.com` (but not `yourdomain.com`). So the wildcard (`*`) domain needs to be the last one in the file so it only catches request that aren't sent to `www` or `app`.